# Responsive 3 columns layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've done the layout for my website which seems to be working fine, but I wanted to make sure I didn't overcomplicated it or used rubbish technique.

So this is how it works, within the DIV I have another div that is a table, and within it I have another 3 divs that are table-cells

```
<div id="container-main">
    <div id="columns-3">
        <div class="main-col-left-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-center-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-right-s"></div>
    <hr>
        <div class="main-col-left-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-center-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-right-s"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each column contains various elements (something like pinterest website).

Now, when I resize, after reaching certain width, I want only 2 colums to be visible, and later only one. While stacking from 3 to 1 is not difficult as it'll happen automatically, the issue was from 3 to 2 columns, so what I did is I gave the middle column `display: none` property when screen gets to small, so it's not shown (and on the backend side I assume data will be transferred to visible column if the current one is hidden).

Is this solution rubbish and there is far better one, or it'll do?

I do not want to have situation when in one row I have 2 columns and in the next one only one, so this CAN'T happen:

```
ǀdataǀdataǀ
ǀdataǀ    ǀ
-----------
ǀdataǀdataǀ
ǀdataǀ    ǀ
```

but it should always be:

```
ǀdataǀdataǀ
ǀdataǀdataǀ
-----------
ǀdataǀdataǀ
ǀdataǀdataǀ
```

Comment: It should be like this, dont add `hr` tag `<div id="columns-3">
        <div class="main-col-left-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-center-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-right-s"></div>
    </div>

<div id="columns-3">
        <div class="main-col-left-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-center-s"></div>
        <div class="main-col-right-s"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: the main problem you have is that your layout is not designed to be responsive; you shouldn't need to change your layout (html structure) as a result of a screen config change, this goes against a responsive design. What you've got is completely different to pinteres and you will need a slightly complex javascript routine to achieve this...as it stands. Recommendation, get rid of that intrusive `hr`, this the main hurdle I can see here

Comment: Hr is not required indeed and I used it just to mark divisions between rows. I forgot to mention that I obviously use media queries, but I want to be able to switch from 3 columns to 2 columns without having them stacked unevenly as per example above. So I understand that hiding central column is not a good practice, and there is no pure css solution for that? In that case what sort of js-magic solution shall I google? Pinterest solution seem to be bit clumsy to me though (that is adding margins).

Comment: @Pejs that makes sense...well, it is possible, kind of. I'll put my thoughts in an answer. Maybe I'll manage to draw some **absolute** geeks' attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. Basically, a css-only solution is possible and recommended. It'd be easy to achieve with CSS3 and the new **Flexible Box Model**, however, browser support is not evenly implemented -even major browsers. So, if you want to support at least all major browsers I'd suggest you stick to the **Traditional Box Model** which is what my answer is based on.

The solution is quite straight forward:

- One block `div` that serves as the container element
- Multiple `div`s (inside the container `div`) displayed `inline-block` which would be your "table cells"

The html structure would be something like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

which would be styled in the following manner...

```
div.container{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
}
div.box{
    width:30%;
    font-size:40px;
    margin:20px 0 0 2.5%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This will display 3 boxes aligned horizontally (in one row) in a responsive manner.The `font-size:0` declaration is a work-around for the [inline-block font spacing issue](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), you can read more about it if you google it, there are other ways to approach this problem.

Now, in order to display only 2 boxes in one row when the screen width is limited, you can use media queries, as below...

```
@media all and (max-width:950px){
    div.box{
        width:47%;
       margin:20px 0 0 2%;
}
```

of course...you can change the `max-width` constraint to something else. Finally, I've put together a fiddler below in order to add some visuals...

```css
div.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#eee;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:0;
}
div.box{
    color:#666;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:30%;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:20px 0 0 2.5%;
    line-height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 5px #ccc;
    text-align:center;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}

@media all and (max-width:950px){
    div.box{
        width:47%;
       margin:20px 0 0 2%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box" style="height:150px">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">11</div>
</div>
```

Notice in the example above that intentionally set the height of box 8

Comment: Fantastic! Simple, smart and does what I wanted even better, as now if I get wider screen, css will stack divs to 3,4,5... columns. Beautiful, thank you very much.

Comment: Just curious - what is the reason behind there being a gap between regular side div and 150px div? Is it because they are stacked from left to right? And is it possible to make divs having always the same vertical spacing regardless their height and without fixed-specyfying webkit-column-count (or that would be a part of media queries solution)?

Comment: @Pejs that's obviously because all other boxes are bigger than 150px...they have a height of 200px. Regarding your last question, you wanted to stack boxes horizontally in the same row -I believe. If you were to maintain the same vertical spacing, you would end up with exactly the Pinterest approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Try something like this in your css file:

```
.main-col-left-s, .main-col-center-s, .main-col-right-s {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .main-col-left-s, .main-col-center-s, .main-col-right-s {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .main-col-left-s, .main-col-center-s, .main-col-right-s {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `float: left` property of css, for your table cells, that makes what you wished for